# SQL: How to display the same item by group and the same group of the dates

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm new to sql and I would need your help.
What I want to do is to display the result like this.
I want to make the "a:0:{}" not be displayed and have the dates be in acsending order becuase the dates are messed up.
How will I display the result like this?

result:

```
a:1:{s:1:"s";s:2:"aa";}              2014-08-12
a:2:{s:1:"s";s:2:"aa";}              2014-08-19
a:1:{s:1:"s";s:2:"aa";}              2014-08-19
a:3:{s:1:"s";s:2:"aa";}              2014-08-20
```

sample sql data

`site` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`created` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,

```
column name site                     column name created

a:0:{}                               2014-08-18
a:0:{}                               2014-08-18
a:0:{}                               2014-08-18
a:0:{}                               2014-08-18
a:1:{s:1:"s";s:2:"aa";}              2014-08-19
a:2:{s:1:"s";s:2:"aa";}              2014-08-20
a:1:{s:1:"s";s:2:"aa";}              2014-08-19
a:3:{s:1:"s";s:2:"aa";}              2014-08-12
```

Comment: Plz add some dummy data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following mysql query. You will get the count as you need.

```
select count(site) 
from coming 
group by site , DATE(created)
```

Comment: Take it eassy. Happy developing.